# How to issue warning in Pycharm when keyword is used

Tags: python, pycharm, code-inspection

I'm working on a project in Pycharm as part of a team.
Part of our coding conventions is banning the use of a specific keyword.

I'm worried about accidental usage of that word, so I want Pycharm to issue a warning if it encounters it when I run its code inspection.

Is there any way to configure that?

Comment: There's no such feature to my knowledge. Do you use any external linter? I think it should be quite straightforward to extend e.g. `pylint` to ensure no banned keywords are used.

Comment: It's also possible to achieve by a plugin: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html